# SQL to combine child records by joining parent record

Tags: sql, firebird

First let me apologize if this doesn't make any sense. I took me some time to write it up and understand it myself. I apologize if there is anything that is confusing. I am new to this and did my best to explain. I also apologize for the qustion title, if it doesn't represent. If someone knows of a better title, please edit or make any changes necessary.

I have two tables JOBS and PHASES.

```
JOBS
Id
Job_Type (ex. 0 = import)
Title

PHASES
Id
Jobs_Id
Phase_Type
Title
Start_Time
End_Time
Duration
```

Each job/job_type can have any number of phases - each phase has a start, end, and duration time

I want to select the fields jobs_id, start_time, end_time, and duration from the PHASES table
and add up all their Durations for each job_type (example: job_type = 0 which is an import job)

```
SELECT jobs_id, start_time, end_time, duration FROM phases 
JOIN jobs ON phase.jobs_id = jobs.id
WHERE jobs.job_type=0
```

return jobs_id
return the earlist start time as start
return the lastest endtime as end
return the total duration of them all TotalDuration

Example, if the following data was in the JOBS table (Id, Job_Type, Title)

```
1, 0, Import
```

and the following data was in PHASES table (id, job_id, phase_type, title, start, end, duration)

```
1, 1, 1, 0, Run Preprocessor, 10/18/2012 8:52 PM, 10/18/2012 9:00 PM, 00:08:00
2, 1, 2, 1, Massage Data, 10/18/2012 9:00 PM, 10/18/2012 9:05 PM, 00:05:00
3, 1, 3, 2, Run Postprocessor, 10/18/2012 9:05 PM, 10/18/2012 9:07 PM, 00:02:00

4, 2, 1, 0, Run Preprocessor, 10/18/2012 9:15 PM, 10/18/2012 9:20 PM, 00:05:00
5, 2, 2, 1, Massage Data, 10/18/2012 9:20 PM, 10/18/2012 9:25 PM, 00:05:00
6, 2, 3, 2, Run Postprocessor, 10/18/2012 9:30 PM, 10/18/2012 9:35 PM, 00:05:00
```

Above shows the imformation (phases) of two jobs (job_type = 0)

I need an SQL statement that can combine the phases and show the earlist start and latest end, and the total duration. I would expect this information returned (Job_id, Start, End, TotalDuration)

```
 1, 10/18/2012 8:52 PM, 10/18/2012 9:07 PM, 00:05:00
 2, 10/18/2012 9:15 PM, 10/18/2012 9:35 PM, 00:15:00
```

Comment: sql-server, mysql, nosql, oracle, sqlite, postgresql?

Comment: Need it to work for Oracle, MS SQL Server, and Firebird - but it would be nice if it could work accross all databases using ANSI SQL

Comment: That won't happen because differencing dates and/or display in HH:MM:SS are *both* non-standard operations. There is no equivalent statement to do either aspect on all 3 of those DBMS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your total durations will not go beyond 1 day, this will work.  If it goes beyond one day, an additional expression will be required to preceed the `HH:MM:SS` in the duration column.

```
select job_id,
       min(start_time) start_time,
       max(end_time) end_time,
       CONVERT(CHAR(8), max(end_time)-min(start_time), 8) totalduration
  from phases
 group by job_id

-- sample data --
create table phases (job_id int, start_time datetime, end_time datetime);
insert phases values (1, '20121019 12:45', '20121019 13:15');
insert phases values (1, '20121019 13:15', '20121019 13:45');
insert phases values (1, '20121019 14:00', '20121019 15:12');

-- result --
job_id  start_time               end_time                 totalduration
1       2012-10-19 12:45:00.000  2012-10-19 15:12:00.000  02:27:00
```

Comment: This does not find all those with the Job_type = 0 (which you need to reach over to the jobs table - by link of jobs.id = phases.job_id.

Comment: I removed the CONVERT(CHAR(8)) typecast from around the max(end_time)-min(start_time), 8) totalduration   and added the where clause. I dont know why yet, but the CHAR was throwing an error. Is that typecast standard ANSI SQL accross all databases? - thanx

Comment: Works against MS SQL Server, but not forebird

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @jobs TABLE(
    jobid BIGINT NOT NULL
)

INSERT INTO @jobs (jobid)
VALUES (1)
, (2)
, (3)



DECLARE @phases TABLE(
    phaseId BIGINT NOT NULL,
    jobId BIGINT NOT NULL,
    startTime datetime not null,
    endTime datetime not null
)

INSERT INTO @phases (phaseId, jobId, startTime, endTime)
VALUES (1,1, '10/18/2012 8:52 PM', ' 10/18/2012 9:00 PM')
, (2, 1, '10/18/2012 9:00 PM', '10/18/2012 9:05 PM')
, (3, 1, '10/18/2012 9:05 PM', '10/18/2012 9:07 PM')
, (4, 2, '10/18/2012 9:15 PM', '10/18/2012 9:20 PM')
, (5, 2, '10/18/2012 9:20 PM', '10/18/2012 9:25 PM')
, (6, 2, '10/18/2012 9:30 PM', '10/18/2012 9:35 PM')


SELECT j.jobid, MIN(p.startTime) as startTime
, MAX(p.endTime) as endTime
, CONVERT(TIME(0),MAX(p.endTime)-MIN(p.startTime)) as duration
FROM @phases p
JOIN @jobs j ON j.jobid = p.jobId
GROUP BY j.jobid
```

Comment: The duration is looking like (0.000279653) How do I convert that duration into HH:MM:SS ?

Comment: This also does not find all those with the Job_type = 0 (which you need to reach over to the jobs table - by link of jobs.id = phases.job_id

Comment: I guess just adding a WHERE clause fixes the issue of Job_type - WHERE j.job_type=0